# Conditional place data into a prebuilt report

Tags: r, excel, report

It's quite an interesting challenge, and I can't say that I entirely know how/the best way to go about it. 
Basically I have a data set, I have attached a few picture to try and show you what I am working with. The data was randomly generated but it similar to what I am working with. 
[image: Data]
[image: Report_Part1][image: Report_Part2]

I am wanting to take the data, then input the date and value into the report based on the category, and date. The even more challenging part of it is that I need to have to report be filled out for each unique id. So it will have to create many different reports, and then fill it out.

Any idea/questions? I have no idea how to go about it. 
I am experienced in R, excel, some python and SQL (but very little).

Comment: If this is in excel then VBA would be a good fit.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am not all that experienced when it comes to writing macros.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dataset in R, you could write a function that takes the parameters needed, performs the aggregation, and writes the result to excel.

It is not clear to me what exactly the data aggregation part is. Without reproducible data it is hard to go into more detail.